# javascript some button clicks dont refresh page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright so I got two buttons, one adds a dog to the doglist and another one clears the whole list.

Both work fine, just one thing that's bothering me is that only the OnSubmit button refreshes page.

The dog list is loaded in OnReady, and the list only gets refreshed when an item is added. When I clear the list I need to manually refresh the page to see changes.

```
function OnSubmit(event) {
    addToStorageList(dogs, dog);
}

function OnClickClearList() {
    localStorage.setItem('dogs', JSON.stringify([]));
}    

function addToStorageList(listName, itemToAdd) {
    var list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(listName));  
    if (!Array.isArray(list)) {
        list = [];
    }
    list.push(itemToAdd);
    localStorage.setItem(listName, JSON.stringify(list));   
}

$('#btn1').click(OnSubmit);

$('#btn2').click(OnClickClearList);
```

I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need to set `type="submit"` on the second button. If you could add your HTML to the question we could tell you for sure.

Comment: Both buttons do not have a type

Comment: Are the buttons `<button>`s or `<input>s`? Or are they in a form. Sounds like you're hitting a default browser action. You should add your HTML to the question.

Comment: they are <button> and both are exactly the same html-side, only difference is one goes to OnSubmit and other goes to the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion noone of them should refresh, to refresh you should use

"location.reload(); "

in the end of your functions

the reason one of them refreshes is either in code I cannot see (that you havn't posted) or that one is called OnSubmit and that is interfering with form submit buttons or something

Comment: Hmm okay, could it be better to redirect all buttons to OnSubmit and seperate them using ids?

Comment: That is up to you, but for me the "OnSubmit" into refresh is "Undefined behavior" so I would use "location.reload()" and maybe even rename the funtion just in case, as that might be browser specific behavior

Comment: Alright thanks I'll use reload() for now on for buttons that are not for a form. How would you go about handling multiple form buttons though? (In case I want more forms)

Comment: As long as there is "One" submit button per form, nothing special is required, as you can make "hidden" inputs (or make them go to diff pages), if you have multiple buttons per form you should name them and give them values. This is however a whole other context then the one I talked about above, as above I intended it not to be about forms

Comment: How about having multiple forms with a single button using onSubmit(), wouldn't all those buttons do the same? How do you differentiate them?

Comment: Humm, as I feel we dragging of topic, to put it breif, it feels that I have to little information to understand your questions, it feel like you are in a mess of injecting into a default html form tag behavior, and messing server and client side. If you do a form it's a datapackage, that you send to your server, it's at the servers position you need to tell the different packages appart. This is because you use a form (you reload the page) so you have to have a server to store the changes, a.k.a you should be able to accomplish what you want with raw html, and imo remove the javascript part.